# Elements from owl carousel slide are displayed before css animation take place

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, slide, owl-carousel

Elements from owl-carousel slides are being displayed right before the animation starts (fadeInUp and zoomIn). They shoudn`t be visible before animations. In the first slide they behave well, but in second one , you can see they are always appearing right before css animations take place.

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6k8agot1/

```js
//Start Hero slider initialize code
$(document).ready(function(){
var heroSlider = $('.owl-carousel');
heroSlider.owlCarousel({
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
animateIn: 'fadeIn',
autoplayTimeout:5000,
autoplayHoverPause: true,

loop: true,
margin: 0,
nav: false,
mouseDrag:false,
touchDrag:true,
pullDrag:false,
freeDrag:false,
dots:true,
autoplay:true,
responsive: {
0: {
items: 1
},
600: {
items: 1
},
1000: {
items: 1
}
}
});
// End Hero slider initialize code
// Start Reactivate css animation every time a slide is loaded
heroSlider.on("changed.owl.carousel", function(event){
// selecting the current active item
var item = event.item.index-2;
// first removing animation for all captions
$('h1, p').removeClass('fadeInUp');
$('a').removeClass('zoomIn');
$('.owl-item').not('.cloned').eq(item).find('h1, p').addClass(' fadeInUp');
$('.owl-item').not('.cloned').eq(item).find('a').addClass(' zoomIn');


})
});
```

```css
/*Start buttons*/
.btn.btn-default {
display: inline-block;
border:none;
color: #fff;
padding:15px;
border-radius: 38px;
position: relative;
background-color: #4ac8ed;
z-index: 1;

}
.btn.btn-default:after {
position: absolute;
border:none;
content: '';
top: 0;
color:white;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 38px;
background:#2f7c93;
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 0;
}
.btn.btn-default:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
}
.btn.btn-default i {
-webkit-transition: .5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition:  .3s ease;
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin:0;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn.btn-default:hover i {
transform: translateX(5px);
}
.btn.btn-default b, i, span {
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
}
/*End buttons*/



.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:focus {
outline: none!important;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
pointer-events: none;
}
.padding_zero {overflow:hidden;  }
.centered {
position: absolute;
margin-top:-250px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 100%;
}
.centered span { font-weight:700;}

 .fadeInUp {
animation-duration: .8s!important;
animation-delay: .8s;
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

 to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);

  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}



.fadeInUp {
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}


.it1 .zoomIn {
animation-duration: .8s!important;
animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.it2 .zoomIn {
animation-duration: .8s!important;
animation-delay: 1s;
}
.item1 b { font-size:14px; font-weight:300;}
.item1 h1 {font-size:65px; line-height: 65px;}
.item1 p {font-size: 20px; }

.item2  h1 {font-size: 65px; }
.item2  p { font-size:20px; }
.item2  b {font-size:14px; font-weight:300;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid padding_zero ">
    <div class="row justify-content-center ">
      
      <div class="col-12  col-md-12 ">
        
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme ">
          <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
          <div class="item " >
            <img src="http://divcake.com/temp2/images/forest1.jpg" alt="" >
            <div class="centered centered1 col-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4  text-center item1 text-white">
              <h1 class="animated fadeInUp mr-0  ">Start your project with us!</h1>
              <p class="fadeInUp my-1 my-md-4 animated "> - Make your great ideas become reality - <br>We have the solution</p>
              
              <div class="it1">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default px-3 py-1 px-md-4 py-md-2 zoomIn  animated"><b> START PROJECT</b> <i class="fas fa-caret-right "></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
          <div class="item  ">
            <img  src="http://divcake.com/temp2/images/proba2.jpg"   alt="" >
            <div class="centered text-center col-10 col-md-6 item2 text-dark ">
              <p class="mb-3 " >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
              <h1 >Lorem2 ipsum dolor.</h1>
               <div class="it2">
                <a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-default px-3 py-1 px-md-4 py-md-2 "><b>CONTACT</b> <i class="fas fa-caret-right "></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is arising because you are making the changes after the slide transition has been completed. Using '**translate**' event instead of '**changed**' should help.

Try changing

heroSlider.on("**changed**.owl.carousel", function(event){});

to

heroSlider.on("**translate**.owl.carousel", function(event){});

Also keep the classes consistent across the owl carousel items, The **animated** class was missing in the second carousel item children.

```
<h1 class="animated mr-0"></h1>
<p class="my-1 my-md-4 animated"></p>
<a class=" animated"></a>
```

Comment: It`s not working... but you can test the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/6k8agot1/

Comment: Try now, I made a mistake earlier, it was translate and not transition. Also add the animated class for the second carousel item children. And don't add the fadeInUp classes here. The script will add it.